# Scraping or reading Kafka metrics

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, metrics

My Service is running in K8s and consumer of Kafka Topics. Metrics related to Kafka topics for example like number of requests in a topic etc are available in Kafka cluster. Is there a way to scrape or read those metrics and store in my own way in my own repository.

If yes, What do I need to use?

Comment: There's a lot of approaches, with different "best-practices" depending on the stats you want.  Could you list out ~4-5 metrics you're wanting to consume? "Number of messages" in a topic is one you mentioned

Comment: You need a JMX exporter, like Prometheus

Comment: Something like 1. Total messages per second coming in to specific topic.
2. Total messages currently on Topic
3. Bytes in rate
4. Bytes out rate
I can easily control metrics like
5. What is my consumption speed
6. Offset rate